# How to fix problem of inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sample

I am trying to use KNeighborsClassifier to predict if the output(Y) is 0 or 1 based on six inputs(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6). For this i wrote codeds below.

The data is occured by 126 rows × 7 columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("ACME-HappinessSurvey2020.csv")
[enter image description here][1]
y = np.array(data["Y"])
x = np.array(data.drop(["Y"],axis = 1))

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.4)
predicted = KNeighborsClassifier()
predicted.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
succes =predicted.score(xtest,ytest)
```

and the accuracy needs to reach at least 73% or above but as i increase the test size, it doesn't reach to even 60% accuracy

is there a way to inreace it ?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match your real question. Which is your problem exactly?

Comment: i wanna reach to 70% percent or above accuracy this is why i change the test size but it does not reach, is it possible to reach or not ?

Comment: Previously you had a problem with the train_test_split function. And you reach the error of the inconsistent number of samples. But I have seen you solved it. About your question about the accuracy, I don't know if it's possible. It depends on your dataset (and I can't see it). I will recommend you tune some hyperparameters of the KNeighborsClassifier, or even using another classification algorithm like Random Forest. The KN algorithm is probably too simple.